# IE 10+ Transition From display:none Not Working

Tags: transform, transition, internet-explorer-10

The problem I'm facing is that when I click on a button to show this element, on IE 10 it doesn't show up. I'm adding the `display: block` property via JavaScript, that's why it's not in the CSS. It works on all other browsers except IE.

If I remove the transition it shows up.

```css
section {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transform: translate(0,-300%);
}

section.visible {
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Please share a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). I am unable to repro the issue in [the fiddle I created](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/ptttsn72/).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by showing the section when adding `display: block` on the visible class rather than using jQuery `show()`. Guess IE10+ has issues with that.